# 'Unmet dependencies ' on updating 16.04

Tags: package-management, updates

welcome,
I need help, please
This error message appeared for me to update Ubuntu 16.04 :

---

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 messengerfordesktop : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installed or
                                libappindicator but it is not installable or
                                libappindicator-gtk3 but it is not installable
                       Recommends: hunspell
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.5.0 but it is not installed
            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

I am honored to help you, thanks in advance

Comment: Your messages do not look accurate, but did you do what it suggested, which I believe is `sudo apt-get -f install`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libept1.5.0 which is found in 'universe', do you have it enabled?)

Comment: Thank you, the system has now started to update